# Как с помощью JQuery присвоить margin значение, полученное формулой

Tags: jquery, margin

C помощью JQuery считываю фактическое значение высоты блока .radiusс_name1 , в котором находится текст (1-3 строки). Помимо этого считываю высоту родительского блока .radiusс, и вычитанием высот с последующим делением пополам получаю значение, записываемое в переменную  $(MRG). 
После чего мне нужно классу .radiusс_name1 присвоить значение полученное переменной  $(MRG) в стиле свойством margin-top. Это нужно для вертикального позиционирования .radiusс_name1(исходя из фактического значения высоты) по центру родительского блока.

На данном этапе код в таком состоянии:

```
jQuery(document).ready(

  function() 
  {
    $(MRG) = (( $('.radiusс').height - $('.radiusс_name1').height)/2) 
 (
   function(){
    $('.radiusс_name1').css('margin-top',  $(MRG) +'px');
  })});
```

Просто присвоить классу какое-либо значение конкретное значение-получается, а вот с формулой что-то не выходит. Грешу конечно на синтаксис. Но пока попытки что-то изменить безуспешны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mrg = ($('.radiusс').height() - $('.radiusс_name1').height()) / 2;
  $('.radiusс_name1').css('margin-top',  mrg + 'px');
});
```